# disable browser automatically option (display saved words from input element)

Tags: javascript, browser, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

In input text, if write for example word: "ford", browser saves this word and second time, if write in input text symbol "f", below input element, browser displays this word (ford) yes?
I have in site input element and I want disable this option for my input element. please tell, how to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't know that this is called autocomplete. Once you know that you'll have an easier time finding info about it.

See: [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)